# React error even after using DefinePlugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I am using React 15.4.2 and Redux 3.6.0 with Webpack and this is my webpack.config.js file contents: (some of the code is omitted for brevity)

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextWebpackPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');

const pkg = require('./package.json');

const TARGET = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
const PATHS = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'src/js'),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
};

process.env.BABEL_ENV = TARGET;

const common = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  entry: {
    app: PATHS.src
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.dist,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ['babel?cacheDirectory'], include: PATHS.src },
      { test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'] },
      { test: /(\.ttf|\.woff2?|\.eot|\.svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'url' },
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'url?limit=10000!img?progressive=true' },
      { test: /\.json/, loaders: ['json']}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    })
  ]
};

if (TARGET === 'build') {
  module.exports = merge(common, {
    entry: {
      vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
    },
    output: {
      path: PATHS.dist,
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
      chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextWebpackPlugin.extract('style', 'css'), include: PATHS.src }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production')
      }),
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      }),
      new CleanWebpackPlugin([PATHS.dist]),
      new ExtractTextWebpackPlugin('[name].[chunkhash].css'),
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
      })
    ]
  });
}
```

Running `npm run build` gives the minified code. But it still gives the error

`Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to use the production build which skips development warnings and is faster. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#use-the-production-build for more details.`

I have also tried reordering the plugins in build TARGET, but its giving the same error.

What am I missing here?

P.S. Redux gives the same minification error too.

**EDIT**

This is my package.json build script:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress"
  ...
}
```

**EDIT #2**

This is the output to a console.log statement from within the application.

[image: console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV:', process.env.NODE_ENV);]

Comment: its giving you error because while compiling code, your NODE_ENV is not set to production, its something else. try executing `export NODE_ENV=production` before running webpack

Comment: This is my build script:

`"build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress"`

Comment: If you are testing on your local environment then don't use the UglifyJs plugin of webpack.

Comment: So, I should minify using -p option? @Vikramaditya

Comment: No, don't do any minification/optimization for local environment, only use those things in production.

Comment: I am using it in production. I am getting this error when deployed in production.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this syntax for the DefinePlugin.

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env':{
    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
  }
}),
```

Comment: I simply separate the two config files, one for develop and one for production. The command for production build is "webpack --config webpack-production.config.js --progress --colors".

Comment: Even then, the syntax for adding the plugin, would be one of the two. Neither of those are working.

Comment: The prod. env you display in the browser show that it is in 'production' env which is normal. However, the problem should be during the webpack build process, the node env is not 'production'. That cause the warning when you run that output in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled source maps to see that its a package I have been using that was minified using non-standard ways. So, setting NODE_ENV to 'production' had no effect on the said package. Nevertheless, my Webpack config and my build scripts have been working perfectly fine. Thank you for your help guys!